# perl script/regex to avoid a particular pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to look for a pattern in files and perform an operation if the pattern is found. The pattern is `class <class_name> extends`. But I want to exclude the case in which I encounter the pattern `//class <class_name> extends` i.e. I want to skip the operation when I get commented  lines.

```
open my $fh, "<", $file_t or die "can't read open '$file_t': $OS_ERROR";        # Opening the file
while (<$fh>) {

    if(/class\s{1,10}<class_name>\s{1,10}extends/){
        #Perform the operation if we find above pattern
    }
 close $fh or die "can't read close '$file_t': $OS_ERROR";                      #Closing the file
}
```

How do I include the piece of code to exclude the pattern I mentioned.
Thanks for the help.

***********Edits************

I think I have to re-frame my question. I also want to ensure that when I look for `class <class_name> extends` I should look for that pattern only and not if that pattern exists along with a `//` before it. Something like, doing a "if and only if" that particular pattern exists with no other combination of characters.

Comment: Are you trying to include this in your Regex expression? If not, a separate Regex with an or should work just fine.

Comment: @KRichardson: a separate Regex will not say if `//` is before or after the target.

Comment: @Richardson, In the separate regex I am trying, I am unable to figure out how to include `//` as it is interpreting it differently.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, fair point. I was assuming the `//` would be at the start of the line, and could easily be checked with something like `/^\s*\/\//`

Comment: If your question was answered, click the empty checkmark next to an answer to mark it correct. Otherwise, refine the question.

Comment: @Andy Ray
Thanks for checking with my question. Yes, I accepted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to only allow whitespace before the definition (if classes can declared in indented scopes)

```
/^\s*class\s+<class_name>\s+extends/
```

Explanation

```
^ Start of line
\s* 0 or more whitespace characters
```

Comment: one problem might be the `public` (or similar) modifier

Comment: @Andy Ray Yes, this solution works too. Nice idea and thank you.
@K Richardson   I am not sure with the modifier though.

Comment: If keywords can precede, you can use `/^[\w\s]*\bclass.../`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to include the check in the same Regex expression (rather than tying two together with an `and`, you could use negative lookahead:

```
if (m{/^(?:(?!//).)*class\s{1,10}$className\s{1,10}extends}) {
```

Comment: Why `\s{1,10}` spaces? Why not use `\s+`?

Comment: I left that from the code provided by the OP, but yes I agree. If you'd like to edit the answer accordingly, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: The solution didn't work if the "//" was at the very start of the line, but I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution with the help of above comments. I included the below line of code in my code:
`if(/^\s*\/\/class\s{1,10}<class_name>\s{1,10}extends/){next;}`

The new piece of code looks like this:

```
open my $fh, "<", $file_t or die "can't read open '$file_t': $OS_ERROR";        # Opening the file
while (<$fh>) {
if(/^\s*\/\/class\s{1,10}<class_name>\s{1,10}extends/){next;}
elsif(/class\s{1,10}<class_name>\s{1,10}extends/){
    #Perform the operation if we find above pattern
}
close $fh or die "can't read close '$file_t': $OS_ERROR";                      #Closing the file
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That should do it. I found a way that may be helpful in the future using `negative lookahead`.

Comment: Yes, your solution is crisp and helpful. Thank you.